sticky labels printer for mobile html javascript application
I am looking for a way to print little sticky labels. My main application for that task is a webapp using html and javascript on a iphone/android. I need a good printer and prefarably connect to it via the mobile phones bluetooth and print via javascript. Any suggestions?
I have a dymo label printer but it only works with a driver installed on windows. It doesn't work on mobile. Mobile is a requierement.
